# How to define non negative decision variables in CPLEX?

Tags: cplex, opl

Xijcp,Yjkp,Zklp,Wlmp,Amjp,Bmdp,Ddcp, Edrcp, Frjcp greater than or equal to zero for all i,j,k,l,m,d, r, c, p
Hjp,Gkp equal to zero or 1 for all j,k,p

Answer (score 0):

If you define your decision variable as:

`dvar float Xijcp;` --> it can take both negative and positive values.

For greater than equal to zero, you can define as

```
dvar float+ Xijcp;
```

For binary variables

```
dvar boolean Xijcp;
```